# Rhythmbox not starting Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10, rhythmbox

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 15.10, and whenever I try to open Rhythmbox, it crashes immediately.

Tried the same thing from the terminal, got this.

```
Rhythmbox:ERROR:rb-ext-db.c:362:impl_constructor: code should not be reached
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Used apt-get purge on it, but didn't work; just got the same error. How can I remedy this?

Answer (score 0):

It probably due to a dependency that has not been upgraded correctly.

In these scenarios I would first try to purge rhythmbox and its dependencies before reinstalling.

purge:

```
sudo apt-get purge rhythmbox rhythmbox-plugins gir1.2-rb-3.0 librhythmbox-core9 rhythmbox-data
```

reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rhythmbox
```